# Start reading movie before file is fully copied

Tags: video, streaming

Wifi speed in my flat is not that good, and I often have to copy big video files from my nas to my mac.
In these situations I'd like to be able to start playing the file after few seconds and that the transfer ends in the background while I watch the move.

Is there a video viewer app that handles such a use case?

Answer (score 1):

The free and open-source [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) media player is able to do this.

If the video file is an .avi, a dialog saying "The AVI file is broken. Seeking will not work correctly. Do you want to try to fix it?" may pop up. Simply click "Don't repair" and the video will start playing.